# How to batch crop multiple pictures to a fixed area? Ex. crop a 400x300 section in multiple 1600x2000 pictures

Tags: windows, images, crop

For example, I'd like to crop an area in this yellow rectangle in all pictures of same dimensions (same length and width).

[image]

One use of this may be to crop a bunch of screenshots taken of a video game or program so that only the relevant parts of the image are there.

Comment: NetPBM (open source, multi-platform) is another solution.  I've used it for this sort of task, multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com) to do this.  Once you have it installed, open a command prompt, go to `irfanview` program folder, then convert your images with a command like this:

```
i_view64.exe c:\images\*.jpg /crop=(0,0,500,500,0) /convert=c:\output\*.jpg
```

The 5 numbers in the parenthesis are

1. starting X position
2. starting Y position
3. width
4. height
5. which corner to start with.

you'll have to find these numbers yourself. Once you have the numbers figured out, you can crop all your images with the command above in one go.

Or if you prefer graphical user interface instead of command line, you can open up one of your images using irfarview, press `b` to batch crop/convert your files. you can find crop options by advanced button.

Comment: What's a good way to find the numbers to crop? Is there a software that lines up your picture in a pixel grid?

Comment: irfanview does that as well. Just open your image, drag your mouse to select an area, then you can see the size and location of your selection in the title.

Comment: Great got it. By the way for the corner to start with, are there 4 corners? (So 0 for top left, 1 for top right, 2 for bottom left, 3 for bottom right). I don’t understand that part. I just put 0 like your example and it cropped just fine, but I’d like to understand it.

Comment: I actually tested this myself. you are right, 0 is for top left, so you usually want that. 1 would be top right, so top right corner would have X index 0, top left corner would have the largest X index. Same rule goes for 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the well known free and open-source [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)

Simple example from the [documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop):

```
convert rose: -crop 40x30+10+10  crop.gif
```

Where `40x30+10+10` is the [geometry](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry), basically meaning `width x height + offsetX + offsetY`. All in pixels. Offset is measured from top left corner. Note that there should be no spaces between the numbers and the `x` and `+` signs. I'm adding spaces here for readability.

To run that for a batch of images, you could use OS completion and expansion commands depending on which system you're on. In windows command prompt for example:

```
for %f in (*.png) do (
    convert %f -crop 40x30+10+10 cropped_%f
)
```

In PowerShell:

```
gci *.png | %{ convert -crop 40x30+10+10 $_.FullName ($_.BaseName+"_crop"+$_.Extension)}
```

--- edit

And in Bash:

```
images=$(ls -1 *.png)
for image in $images ; do
    convert -crop 40x30+10+10 cropped_$image
done
```

If you want to recurse through all sub-directories, use:

```
images=$(find -type f -name '*.png')
```